# Dual boot "System doesn't have any USB boot option" issue

Tags: windows, multi-boot

I want to dual boot my laptop, with both Windows 11 (which came with windows 11 preinstalled) and Ubuntu installed.
I prepared a boot disc and from Troubleshooting, chose Use Device.

From there, **i think it is the main problem**, i choose my disc, but written as "[EFI USB Device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIxV5.png)", not UEFI. It ends up with "System doesn't have any USB boot option..." error. I also tried change boot order from BIOS, but Windows started naturally as if there's no boot device plugged.

My disc uses GPT and my BIOS Mode is UEFI.

I am 100% **sure** that my boot disc has no problems (tried on another device).

From BIOS "USB Legacy Support" option is "Enabled" and "Secure Boot" is "Disabled". My motherboard is InsydeH20.

Comment: You may want to try to boot your USB from BIOS/UEFI boot menu. It seems you are currently trying to boot it out of windows.

Comment: @mashuptwice excuse me, can you be more clear about that BIOS/UEFI menu? Because i have seen so many boot menu's and a bit confused.

Comment: Do not disable Secure Boot or your Windows 11 won't work. Some laptop models need "trust" to be enabled in order to boot from external media (many Acer models are notorious for that behavior). You should try anyway from the "one time boot menu" or "boot override menu", if available (it's a different key than the one used to open the firmware settings, UEFI in your case, because Windows 11 doesn't support BIOS or Legacy mode). In a nutshell, read your manual.